# Associativity property for multiple tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

The tensor product has the following properties. Note that all
vector spaces are over the same field .
(Associativity) There exists an isomorphism

$\tau: (V_{1}\otimes....\otimes  V_{n})\otimes(W_{1}\otimes....\otimes W_{m}) \to V_{1}\otimes...\otimes V_{n}\otimes W_{m} \otimes....\otimes W_{m}$

for which
$\tau[((v_{1}\otimes....\otimes  v_{n})\otimes(w_{1}\otimes....\otimes w_{m}))]= v_{1}\otimes...\otimes v_{n}\otimes w_{m} \otimes....\otimes w_{m}$

some idea? i don't know how to start. The other properties are commutativity and the existence of an isomorphism but first i want to see how to prove this isomorphism for associativity and get an idea to continue with the next properties

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez no, i don't know. How to do this for three factors? this can give me a good idea

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez i have the map but i dont't know how to proceed